# Did Canadian children sing the Islamic song "Tala'al badru" to welcome Syrian refugees?

Tags: islam, canada, syria, refugees

Saw [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wd1IU_6rXNk) being shared around in the social media, ostensibly a performance by Canadian children to welcome [Syrian refugees' arrival to Canada](http://www.nytimes.com/2015/12/12/world/americas/syria-refugees-arrive-in-canada.html). I recognized the song as the Islamic song [Tala' al Badru 'Alayna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tala'_al_Badru_'Alayna). According to Wikipedia it was historically sung on Prophet Muhammad's arrival at Medina after a battle.

However the video only show a group of singers, without any meaningful context. For example, was the video really in Canada? Was it as part of welcoming the Syrian refugees, or just a generic Arabic culture performance?

Comment: Does that make it an Islamic song or an Arabic song?

Answer (score 19):

Are these Canadian children? Yes.  Was it part of welcoming Syrian refugees? Sort of.

According to [Buzzfeed](http://www.buzzfeed.com/ishmaeldaro/this-video-of-a-canadian-childrens-choir-singing-an-arabic-s#.roq1WRzrP) the performance took place at the École secondaire publique De La Salle in Ottawa as part of a holiday show earlier this month.

> Canada is accepting 25,000 Syrian refugees, about 2,000 of whom will be settled in the Ottawa region. This year’s pageant included “Tala’ al Badru ‘Alayna” as a symbol of welcome to those who will be starting their new lives in Canada, the CEPEO school board told BuzzFeed Canada.

So while it was meant as a welcome to Syrian refugees there were no Syrian refugees present at the performance.

Comment: Could you clarify the last sentence? I'm not sure I understand the difference between 'to Syrian refugees' and 'for Syrian refugees'

Comment: I edited the last sentence for clarity.  Hope that makes it more clear.